# How to get component reference inside of the model save callback functions?

Tags: javascript, canjs, canjs-model

I have a login component with a model that goes to the server and receives an error if the login was no correct.

Here is the idea of what I'm talking about:

```
var LoginModel = can.Model.extend({
    create : "POST /account/login"
},{});

can.Component.extend({
    tag: "pod-login",
    template: can.view("/static/js/views/login_form.stache"),
    viewModel:{
        login: new LoginModel(),
        processLogin: function(login) {
            // I need to access the component here
        },
        processLoginError: function(response) {
            // I need to access the component here
        }
    },
    events: {
        "#login_button click": function() {
            var form = this.element.find( 'form' );
            var values = can.deparam(form.serialize());
            this.viewModel.login.attr(values).save(
                this.viewModel.processLogin,
                this.viewModel.processLoginError
            );
        }
    }


});
```

The problem here is that when I try to use "this" inside the model login handlers I'm getting an object that ins't the current component instance. On the proessLoginError I got the xhr reference for instance.

How to access the component inside processLogin and processLoginError?

My workaround here was to use $('some_html_element_on_my_template').data('component', this) inside the login_button click event and access it inside the callback functions but I think that this could be handled better.

Any insight guys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to bind context to the callbacks:

    `this.viewModel.login.attr(values).save(
        this.viewModel.processLogin.bind(this),
        this.viewModel.processLoginError.bind(this)
    );`

And don't forget to include `es5-shim` for IE8.